# Value of Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, physics, special-functions

i have encountered the following series on a Physics problem:
\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^n}
\end{equation}

I would like to know if there is any specific Function assigned to this series.
Thanks for you attention.

Comment: Does it not converge for $|x|>1$?

Comment: It seems  that the series converges whenever $|x|>1$. W|A suggests 

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^n} = \frac{\psi^{(0)}_{1/x} (1) + \log(x-1) + \log \frac{1}{x }}{\log x}$$

when $x>1$.

Comment: Mathematica gives $$\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{x}}^{(0)}(1)+\log (x-1)+\log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\log
   (x)}$$ where $\psi_q$ is the [Polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html). The series converges when $|x|>1$

Comment: @Tolaso Well it seems we did the same thing 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yep. Hehe! Great minds think alike. :)

Comment: See also [Lambert Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series).

Comment: Thank you very much